# Update RecyclerView from menu

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have a MainActivity with two fragments. The second fragment has RecyclerView. There is  TextView ( lesson name) and ImageView(show lesson status, if it is done or not) in  RecyclerView . When you click TextView, it  calls another Activity with lesson. After you make the lesson you will go back to MainActivity. After that lessons ImageView will be changed from nothing to resourse 'ic_lessondone'. Also there is a menu in MainActivity. Menu have item 'Reset lessons'. When you press 'Reset lessons' all ImageViews wont show any images. So there are two problems. 1) if I do, for example , only 6th lesson. I will have image 'lessondone'.  When i press 'Reset lessons' image will disappear.  But  when i go back to menu again and press 'Reset lessons', Image will appear again and rise  to previous lesson ( 5th). 2) If i switch off display, image will also  appear to previous lessons  till to 0th.
Its seems i have a problem with onResume.
Help me please.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        final ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
        ab.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu);
        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        if (navigationView != null)
        {
            setupDrawerContent(navigationView);
        }

        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        if (viewPager != null)
        {
            setupViewPager(viewPager);
        }

        // Круглая кнопка
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view)
                {
                    Snackbar.make(view, "Here's a Snackbar", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
                }
            });

        //  Картинки для табов  
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_home);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_lessons);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.sample_actions, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        switch (AppCompatDelegate.getDefaultNightMode())
        {
            case AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM:
                menu.findItem(R.id.menu_night_mode_system).setChecked(true);
                break;
            case AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_AUTO:
                menu.findItem(R.id.menu_night_mode_auto).setChecked(true);
                break;
            case AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES:
                menu.findItem(R.id.menu_night_mode_night).setChecked(true);
                break;
            case AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO:
                menu.findItem(R.id.menu_night_mode_day).setChecked(true);
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            case android.R.id.home:
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                return true;
            case R.id.menu_night_mode_system:
                setNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM);
                break;
            case R.id.menu_night_mode_day:
                setNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
                break;
            case R.id.menu_night_mode_night:
                setNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
                break;
            case R.id.menu_night_mode_auto:
                setNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_AUTO);
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void setNightMode(@AppCompatDelegate.NightMode int nightMode)
    {
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(nightMode);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11)
        {
            recreate();
        }
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager)
    {
        Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new Fragment(), "");
        adapter.addFragment(new LessonsListFragment(), "");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    // Главное меню
    private void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView)
    {
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
            new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem)
                {
                    menuItem.setChecked(true);
                    if (menuItem.getTitle().equals("Reset lessons"))
                    {
                        // Обнуляем файл с рузультатами уроков
                        LessonsListFragment.sLessonsPref.edit().clear().commit();             
                        // Перерисовываем весь писок уроков                    
                        LessonsListFragment.rv.getAdapter().notifyItemRangeChanged(0, LessonsListFragment.rv.getAdapter().getItemCount());
                    }
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    return true;
                }
            });
    }

    static class Adapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
    {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragments = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitles = new ArrayList<>();

        public Adapter(FragmentManager fm)
        {
            super(fm);
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title)
        {
            mFragments.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitles.add(title);
        }

        // Получаем конкретный фрагмент
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position)
        {
            return mFragments.get(position);
        }

        // Количество фрагментов для viewpager (2)
        @Override
        public int getCount()
        {
            return mFragments.size();
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position)
        {
            return mFragmentTitles.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

Fragment

```
public class LessonsListFragment extends Fragment
{
    // Уроки
    // static private Map<String,?> mLessonsKeys ;
    static SharedPreferences  sLessonsPref;
    static RecyclerView rv;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        loadSharedPreferenses();
        rv = (RecyclerView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cheese_list, container, false);
        setupRecyclerView(rv);
        return rv;
    }

    // Загружаем список пройденных уроков
    public void loadSharedPreferenses()
    {
        sLessonsPref = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("LessonsResults", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    // Количество строк в листе
    private void setupRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView)
    {
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(recyclerView.getContext()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new SimpleStringRecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(), getRandomSublist(Cheeses.sCheeseStrings, Cheeses.sCheeseStrings.length)));
    }

    // Задаем Строки
    private List<String> getRandomSublist(String[] array, int amount)
    {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>(amount);
        //Random random = new Random();
        while (list.size() < amount)
        {
            list.add(array[list.size()]);
        }
        return list;
    }


    //Отработка перерисования окна, при возврате к ней
    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        //loadSharedPreferenses();
        //Toast.makeText(null, "Refreshed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (rv.getAdapter() != null)
        {
            rv.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }


// Адаптер 
    public static class SimpleStringRecyclerViewAdapter
    extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SimpleStringRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>
    {

        private final TypedValue mTypedValue = new TypedValue();
        private int mBackground;
        private List<String> mValues;

        public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        {
            // Номер урока, передается в webactivity
            public int mLessonNumber;

            public final View mView;
            public final ImageView mImageView;
            public final TextView mTextView;

            public ViewHolder(View view)
            {
                super(view);
                mView = view;
                mImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.avatar);
                mTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            }

            @Override
            public String toString()
            {
                return super.toString() + " '" + mTextView.getText();
            }
        }

        public String getValueAt(int position)
        {
            return mValues.get(position);
        }

        public SimpleStringRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<String> items)
        {
            context.getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.selectableItemBackground, mTypedValue, true);
            mBackground = mTypedValue.resourceId;
            mValues = items;

        }

        // Создаем холдер с полезной нагрузкой
        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
        {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
            view.setBackgroundResource(mBackground);
            return new ViewHolder(view);
        }

        //Создаем список уроков
        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position)
        {

            holder.mLessonNumber = position + 1;
            // Увеличиваем позицион на 1 что не было 0 урока
            holder.mTextView.setText((position + 1) + " " + mValues.get(position));

            // Если урок пройден
            String finished = sLessonsPref.getString((position + 1) + "", "");
            if (finished.equals("1"))
            {
                // Меняем его цвет
                //holder.mTextView.setTextColor(R.color.white);
                Glide.with(holder.mImageView.getContext()).load(R.drawable.ic_lessondone)
                    //.load(Cheeses.getRandomCheeseDrawable())
                    .fitCenter()
                    .into(holder.mImageView);
                Log.d("Glide", "Work");
            }
            else
            {
                holder.mTextView.setTextColor(R.color.black);
                // holder.mImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            // Вызов WebActivity
            holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {
                        Context context = v.getContext();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(context, WebActivity.class);
                        // Передаем вебвью номер урока и запускаем ее
                        intent.putExtra(WebActivity.EXTRA_NAME, holder.mLessonNumber);
                        context.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
        }
        // Определяем количество выводимых строк
        @Override
        public int getItemCount()
        {
            return mValues.size();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in else statement. I added there this code, and now its ok. notifydatachanged work correctly from navigationview

```
 if (finished.equals("1"))
            {
                // Меняем его цвет
                //holder.mTextView.setTextColor(R.color.white);
                Glide.with(holder.mImageView.getContext()).load(R.drawable.ic_lessondone)

                    .fitCenter()
                    .into(holder.mImageView);
                Log.d("Glide", "Work");
            }
            else
            {
                        Glide.with(holder.mImageView.getContext()).load(R.color.white)
                    .fitCenter()
                    .into(holder.mImageView);
          holder.mTextView.setTextColor(R.color.black);

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement a `reset()` method in the adapter that mark all items as "not done" and then try:

```
LessonsListFragment.rv.getAdapter().reset();
LessonsListFragment.rv.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
```

instead of:

```
LessonsListFragment.rv.getAdapter().notifyItemRangeChanged(0, LessonsListFragment.rv.getAdapter().getItemCount());
```

inside `onNavigationItemSelected`.

Also, you shouldn't be using static variables (like `static RecyclerView rv`), use `private` vars with getters

Comment: notifyDataSetChanged(); isnt helps. problem is still.

Comment: I cant.  Because there  is no reset() method in RecyclerView.Adapter.